# Create a subdomain and point it to a folder via Godaddy API

Tags: godaddy-api

I am adding an `'A' Record using Godaddy API`, a subdomain is created but it is not pointing to the folder where I need. Please help to do the same, what thing I can use in API to point my subdomain.

https://api.godaddy.com/v1/domains/tfedtech.com/records/?domain=domain.com

```
[{"data": "148.66.122.111","name": "test","ttl": 10800,"type": "A"}]
```

Comment: Did you find any solution for this ?

Comment: Yes, I have used Cpanel api for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found its solution and Used Cpanel API for this
https://api.docs.cpanel.net/cpanel/introduction/

```
$resonse = $this->cpanel->uapi->post->SubDomain->addsubdomain(
                array(
                    "domain" => "$subdomain",
                    "rootdomain" => "tfedtech.com",
                    "dir" => "public_html/panel.tfedtech.com",
                    "disallowdot" => 1
                )
        );
```